# cannot be used as a function

Tags: compiling

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int bus1,bus2,total;
        total=(bus1+bus2)(5*14);
        cout<<"fair is"<<total;
        return 0;
}
```

**I used this command. than compiled using command below,**

```
g++ -otravel travel.cpp
```

**but after that it says,**

> travel.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> travel.cpp:6:24: error: ‘(bus1 + bus2)’ cannot be used as a function

**Help me see the wrong of my codes**

Comment: Please add an operator between the two set of parantheses in this line: `(bus1+bus2)(5*14)`

Comment: saji89 is correct, but more importantly I believe this question is off-topic, as it's a C++ question and is not Ubuntu specific in any way. If anywhere, this question belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm sorry if i did a wrong thing, Now i added a "*" and compiled without any error, Thank you all of who helped me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like homework to me... but:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int bus1,bus2,total=0;
        total=(bus1+bus2)*(5*14);
        cout<<"fair is: "<<total<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote line again and compiled successfully, but i didn't use "<<endl". Is it compulsory?

Comment: endl was to start a new line so it isn't ugly at the beginning of your terminal prompt for the next line...